# django template tag add double quotes to the url generated

Tags: django, templates, url

In index.html :

```
<a href={% url 'clm:clmmap' %}" class="button">Empezemos</a>
```

A click in the button "Empezemos" generates a URL http://localhost:8001/clm/map/%22 (not found error is launched) when it should be http://localhost:8001/clm/map/ , without the %22 (double quote).

the urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('map/', CLMMapView.as_view(), name='clmmap'),
```

and the views.py:

```
class CLMMapView(TemplateView):
   template_name = 'clm.html'
   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
   ...
```

so, why a double quote is added to the URL?

Comment: You have a missing `"` before your `url` tag it should be: `<a href="{% url 'clm:clmmap' %}" class="button">Empezemos</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `"` in your Anchor tag

U are using:

```
<a href={% url 'clm:clmmap' %}" class="button">Empezemos</a>
```

it should be:

```
<a href="{% url 'clm:clmmap' %}" class="button">Empezemos</a>
```